# Configuring Mac osx mail

Tags: mac-osx

I use the Mac os x mail at office but would like to access my e-mails from home (I own a windows system). How can I do this? I know one possible way is to redirect e-mails. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your mail server uses IMAP and not POP3, you can access the mails on the server from as many different clients as you like.

Comment: cool, so i can use my microsoft outlook to access mails from any desktop?